# Custom webpack configuration doesn't hash images

Tags: angular, svg, webpack, build, assets

I'm using angular@8.0.2 and angular-builders/custom-webpack@8.4.1.
I'm trying to hash my assets when building and nothing happens.

This is my **webpack.config.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
  module : {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name:'[name].[hash].[ext]',
          outputPath:'images/',
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

This is the rellevant part of my **angular.json** file:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
```

My project structure:

```
│   angular.json
│   package.json
│   webpack.config.js
│
└───src
    │   favicon.ico
    │   index.html
    │   main.ts
    │   polyfills.ts
    │   styles.scss
    │   test.ts
    │
    ├───app
    │   │   app-routing.module.ts
    │   │   app.component.html
    │   │   app.component.scss
    │   │   app.component.ts
    │   │   app.module.ts
    │   │
    │   └───module
    │       │   module.module.ts
    │       │
    │       └───components
    │           ├───images
    │           │       a.svg
    │           │       b.svg
    │           │       c.svg
    │           │       d.svg
    │           │
    │           ├───component1
    │           │       component1.component.html
    │           │       component1.component.scss
    │           │       component1.component.ts
    │           │
    │           ├───component2
    │           │       component2.component.html
    │           │       component2.component.scss
    │           │       component2.component.spec.ts
    │           │       component2.component.ts
```

When i'm running **ng build --prod** this is what I get:

```
3rdpartylicenses.txt
favicon.ico
index.html
main-es2015.eb1987c86fa74ed8cb58.js
main-es5.eb1987c86fa74ed8cb58.js
polyfills-es2015.d74c0c190b9196b834d3.js
polyfills-es5.bf12ddb50191f9d58a90.js
runtime-es2015.2770a5446ad989574354.js
runtime-es5.2770a5446ad989574354.js
styles.069f02bc2114af319bd8.css
```

As you can see none of the svgs is there.

What I'm doing wrong?